# How to create a ragged dataframe (ragged array style) out of a dataframe with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
  id       V2       V3      V4       V5
1  1   0.0000   1.0000   2.000   3.0000
2  2       NA   0.0000   0.000       NA
3  3   0.0000   0.0000      NA       NA
4  4 125.0605 120.8402 125.095 124.8971
5  5   0.0000   0.0000      NA 163.4609
```

and I want to create a ragged array style dataframe like the following with one column w indicating the number (skipping NA) and another column indicating which id (id also corresponds to each row) this number is from:

```
w             ind
0.0000         1
1.0000         1
2.000          1 
3.0000         1
0.0000         2
0.000          2
0.0000         3
0.0000         3
125.0605       4
120.8402       4
125.095        4
124.8971       4
0.0000         5
0.0000         5
163.4609       5
```

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(1:5, .Label = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5)), V2 = c(0, NA, 0, 125.0605, 0), 
V3 = c(1, 0, 0, 120.8402, 0), V4 = c(2, 0, NA, 125.095, NA
), V5 = c(3, NA, NA, 124.8971, 163.4609)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `t`ranspose the columns of the dataset except the first one, while replicating the first column to create a `data.frame` and remove the `NA` rows with `na.omit`

```
na.omit(data.frame(w =c(t(df[-1])), ind = rep(df$id, each = ncol(df)-1)))
#         w ind
#1    0.0000   1
#2    1.0000   1
#3    2.0000   1
#4    3.0000   1
#6    0.0000   2
#7    0.0000   2
#9    0.0000   3
#10   0.0000   3
#13 125.0605   4
#14 120.8402   4
#15 125.0950   4
#16 124.8971   4
#17   0.0000   5
#18   0.0000   5
#20 163.4609   5
```

---

Or with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_to = 'w') %>% 
    filter(!is.na(w)) %>%
    select(w, ind = id)
# A tibble: 15 x 2
#       w   ind
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1    0      1
# 2    1      1
# 3    2      1
# 4    3      1
# 5    0      2
# 6    0      2
# 7    0      3
# 8    0      3
# 9  125.     4
#10  121.     4
#11  125.     4
#12  125.     4
#13    0      5
#14    0      5
#15  163.     5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `stack`,

```
na.omit(stack(data.frame(t(df)[-1,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

#     values ind
#1    0.0000  X1
#2    1.0000  X1
#3     2.000  X1
#4    3.0000  X1
#6    0.0000  X2
#7     0.000  X2
#9    0.0000  X3
#10   0.0000  X3
#13 125.0605  X4
#14 120.8402  X4
#15  125.095  X4
#16 124.8971  X4
#17   0.0000  X5
#18   0.0000  X5
#20 163.4609  X5
```